# Can I modify a C++ container's values while iterating over it?

Tags: c++, containers

Let's say I've a `vector<int> vals`. I'm iterating over it and changing values to absolute:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = vals.begin(); it != vals.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it < 0) *it = -*it;
}
```

Is this allowed? I'm not changing the size of the `vector<int>` so I don't think it gets invalidated. I think I'm safe. I want to confirm this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. You aren't changing the underlying storage.  Keep in mind, it will not work if you pass the container as `const` in a function like this:

```
void doSomething(const vector<int>& vals)
```

This site talks about this pretty well: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/

Comment: Thenks! I didn't know about const && iterators. From the site: "**If the vector object is const-qualified, the function (`begin()`) returns a const_iterator. Otherwise, it returns an iterator.**"

Comment: Yep. It allows you to write .begin and .end when either `const` or not and still have it work. However, your compiler will yell at you when you try to assign a value to an element using a `const_iterator`. This extends to classes in a container where the class method is declared `const` or not matters if your using a `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 8):

It is safe and allowed for sequence containers (e.g., `array`, `vector` and `deque`).

For a `set` or `multiset`, modification is not allowed (though the compiler may not reject code that attempts to do so).

For a `map` or `multimap`, you must treat the key as constant, but you can modify the value associated with that key (and the same applies to the `unordered_` variants).

By the way, you may want to consider an algorithm instead of the loop you've used above:

```
std::transform(vals.begin(), vals.end(), vals.begin(), ::std::abs);
```

Comment: I'm concerned about the difference between modifying a structure with a fixed-size type like int (as in the example) vs a variable-size type like a string. Like, if I have a vector or even a map made of strings, and I set a value to a larger string, it seems like it could cause the entire container to reallocate or shift around, invalidating the pointers/iterators. Can you point me to an official place where it says the iterators must stay valid even when you change the size of a value?